# How do you createa a Material Text Area in Angular Dart?

Tags: angular-dart

I would like to create a large, multiline text area using material components in Angular Dart. I know I can do:

```
<material-input multiline></material-input>
```

But that starts life as a single line input and grows as the user types. I'm looking for a large text area of fixed size that scrolls as the user types (as explained https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#input-types)

Is this possible with Angular Dart's material components?

Comment: Have you tried above code?

Comment: What above code?

Comment: The one HTML line in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I am not completely understanding your question, but I think you can get what you want by providing a row, and maxRow value.

**Example:**

```
<material-input multiline rows="2" maxRows="2"></material-input>
```

Would create a input that started as two rows high and then didn't grow at all, but scrolled instead.